# How to save an ID of the post to metadata?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Toolset plugin for Wordpress and try to make it save the id of the page where the user fills up the form.

This plugin has "hooks" for it.

[This](https://toolset.com/documentation/programmer-reference/cred-api/#cred_save_data) is what they say about it.

**cred_save_data**

Description

```
This hook allows doing a custom action when post data is saved to the database.
```

Arguments

```
    post_id. The id of the current created or edited post.

    form_data. An associative array of data about current form:
        id. The form of ID.
        post_type. The post type that the form operates on.
        form_type. The type of form - 'new' or 'edit'.
        container_id. Refers to the post_id of the post, page or custom post type that contains the CRED form
```

EXAMPLE:

```
add_action('cred_save_data', 'my_save_data_action',10,2);
function my_save_data_action($post_id, $form_data)
{
    // if a specific form
    if ($form_data['id']==12)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['my_custom_field']))
        {
            // add it to saved post meta
            add_post_meta($post_id, '__my_custom_field', $_POST['my_custom_field'], true);
        }
    }
}
```

so I added this modified PHP code in functions.php of the theme:

```
add_action('cred_save_data', 'my_save_data_action',10,2);
function my_save_data_action($post_id, $form_data)
{
    // if a specific form
    if ($form_data['id']==2080) // the id of the form
    {
        if (isset($_POST['container_id']))
        {
            // add it to saved post meta
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'formetadata', $_POST['container_id'], true);
        }
    }
}
```

where for metadata is a slug for custom field created to collect metadata, including the id of the page, where the form was filled up.

It does not work. The form collects data, creates a post, but the field for metadata remains empty.

What did I do wrong?

I don't have enough knowledge about PHP and may be completely misunderstood instructions...

Comment: I would say the first condition is false. 
Evertything that come from the form is a string. 
So 
`$form_data['id']== "2080")` should work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are no obvious problems with the code you have shown, so there's nothing there for us to go on. You need to debug it to track down where the problem is happening. The first thing is make sure the function is getting called. If it is, check the values are what you expect. Add the following code as the first thing in your `my_save_data_action` function: `var_dump($form_data); echo "<p>my_custom_field in POST: ".$_POST['my_custom_field']."</p>"; die()` and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the docs and your function I see they use the key `container_id` and you use `$_POST['container_id']`.  Im just guessing but it sounds like those are the same `id`?  If so then you can access it via the `$form_data` like below:

```
add_action('cred_save_data', 'my_save_data_action',10,2);
function my_save_data_action($post_id, $form_data)
{
    // if a specific form
    if ($form_data['id']==2080) // the id of the form
    {
        if (isset($_POST['container_id']))
        {
            // add it to saved post meta
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'formetadata', $form_data['container_id'], true);
        }
    }
}
```